# Authorization error on call to server-to-server CloudKit Web Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm attempting to implement some basic integration with CloudKit web services, [following Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW9) for authenticating requests. I've followed some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934615/not-sure-how-to-generate-an-ecdsa-signature-given-a-private-key-and-a-message) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247436/cloudkit-server-to-server-authentication) question as to how to properly authorize requests, and seem to be following all steps correctly, but I'm still getting a 401 `AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error from Apple.

[The endpoint I'm targeting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/LookupRecords/LookupRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH6-SW2) is a POST endpoint for retrieving a record, given a record name.

I've added comments to my code to show the outputs i get at various stages, and I've used an alternative certificate so i'm not providing my genuine private key:

```
def self.signature(parameters, date, image_id)
    #date: 2016-08-14T14:32:20Z

    #parameters: {"records":[{"recordName":"7DBC4FAD-D18C-476A-89FB-14A515098F34"}]}

    encoded_parameters = Digest::SHA256.base64digest(parameters)

    #encoded_parameters: 6gmJ4AvmJgkNY4SJm6ImOxZaZ07J7cih/tRXI0zkRjQ=

    url_subpath = CloudKit.url_subpath

    #url_subpath: /database/1/iCloud.ProjectDent.TwIM/development/public/records/lookup

    message = date + ':' + encoded_parameters + ':' + url_subpath

    #message: 2016-08-14T14:23:35Z:6gmJ4AvmJgkNY4SJm6ImOxZaZ07J7cih/tRXI0zkRjQ=:/database/1/iCloud.ProjectDent.TwIM/development/public/records/lookup

    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read('altkey.pem'))

    signature = private_key.dsa_sign_asn1(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.digest(message))

    #signature: -? WX?xfc???ɔ???,?Ț?Փv?3+Xt!?$R?_Y?×*?,?3??Z-\#?ŭ?Ƿh

    encoded_signature = Base64.strict_encode64(signature)

    #encoded_signature: MEUCIFdYlHhmrxoIY8KW1tT6yZT17bYsP8ia09WTdpEzK1h0AiEA0yRSh39fWYHDlyqJLNgzhr9aLVwj2cWtkse3aA0tGZI=

    return encoded_signature
end

def self.headers(parameters, image_id)
    date = Time.now.utc.iso8601

    signature = self.signature(parameters, date, image_id)

    headers = {
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-KeyID' => CloudKit.key_id,
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date' => date,
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1' => signature
    }

    #headers (key id masked): {"X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-KeyID"=>"123456", "X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date"=>"2016-08-14T14:32:20Z", "X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1"=>"MEUCIFdYlHhmrxoIY8KW1tT6yZT17bYsP8ia09WTdpEzK1h0AiEA0yRSh39fWYHDlyqJLNgzhr9aLVwj2cWtkse3aA0tGZI="}

    return headers
end

def self.fetch_image(image_id)
    url = CloudKit.url
    parameters = CloudKit.parameters(image_id).to_json
    headers = CloudKit.headers(parameters, image_id)

    begin
        response = RestClient.post(url, parameters, headers)
        puts 'response'
        puts response.code
        puts response.to_str
    rescue => e
        puts 'rescued: ' + e.to_s
    end
end
```

The end result is:

> rescued: 401 Unauthorized

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - I do seem to be following all steps correctly. Hopefully the logs can help someone understand where this might be going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the parameters to JSON before signing. And make sure to send the same JSON string as the signed copy.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it to match this solution, which works. Hopefully someone will be able to use this for their own requests.